# DIV cross browser solution using CSS

Tags: css, html, height, cross-browser

I am unable to get my div `height` in cross-browsers(atleast with Chrome and Firefox should looks the same)

Here is the screenshot what I mean to say:

[image]

As you can see there is height diff in firefox as compared to chrome.
I am unable to get work out with its height and I need a better solution to solve this

CSS:

```
    .container {
            width: 500px;
            max-height: 730px;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        }
   .mainbody,.header,.footer {
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .mainbody {
            margin-top: 0;
            min-height: 150px;
            max-height: 615px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
   .header {
            height: 40px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            height: 40px;
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        }
    .footer {
            height: 40px;
            background-color: whiteSmoke;
            border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        }
```

​
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="mainbody">
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
    <p>Body</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

​

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yCSHq/1/)**

Comment: are you using [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) ?

Comment: @matmuchrapna-Nothing except a plain stylesheet with the above mentioned css.

Comment: @Ankit-No,as per you answer you have given recently it didnt work either and can you show me the screenshot with 100% height.

Comment: by the way and offtopic, you are using [wrong vendor prefixes' order](http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/) in the ` .container` selector

Comment: If I test your demo in firefox and chrome the height of both are the same. I think one of your browser has a different zoom level. Press the keys _ctrl_ and _0_ at the same time in both browsers and compare again.

Comment: @scessor-absolutely you're right.Thanks  once again :)

Comment: @scessor-You can post it as an answer i will approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I test your demo in firefox and chrome the height of both are the same. I think one of your browser has a different zoom level. Press the keys *ctrl* and *0* at the same time in both browsers and compare again.

Comment: I've just tested this aswell and agree with this answer, appears Firefox is zoomed in by 1 notch!

Answer (score 1):

*by the way, another answer have been accepted. I post my answer for people with the same problem, but another cause of the problem*

if it is not zoom problem, you can use **reset.css**

with it,  your **[demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/yCSHq/3/)** look the same in all browsers (chrome, firefox, opera and safari from left to right)
[image]